# How to mock the same database call with different parameters twice and match all response values against an array of values?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, mocking

I have a class that has a method `team_names`. In this method I iterate through each team object (there is always only two teams in the array) that has a format of `{ id: 'some_id' }` and make a request to Mongo database trying to retrieve each team from `teams` collection. In the end I return an array of team names. I use this data for generating the subject for user email.

I want to test if I get the correct teams. So I have a mock for getting a team from database.

Here is my class:

```rb
class MyEmail
  def initialize(event)
    @teams = event['performers']
  end

  def team_names
    @teams.map do |team| 
      MyMongoGem::DB['teams'].find('_id' => BSON::ObjectId.from_string(team['id'])).first['name']
    end
  end

  def subject
    "Hello from - #{team_names.join(' and ')"
  end

  def deliver!
    # send email
  end
end
```

Now the test looks like this:

```rb
describe MyEmail do
  let(:team_1_id) { BSON::ObjectId.new }
  let(:team_2_id) { BSON::ObjectId.new }
  let(:team_1) do
    {
      'id' => team_1_id.to_s,
      'name' => 'Cats'
    }
  end
  let(:team_2) do
    {
      'id' => team_2_id.to_s,
      'name' => 'Dogs'
    }
  end
  let(:teams) { [team_1, team_2] }
  let(:event) { { name: "some event", performers: teams} }

  subject { described_class.new(event) }

  before do
    allow(MyMongoGem::DB['teams']).to receive_message_chain(:find, :first)
      .with(any_args)
      .and_return team_1

    subject.deliver!
  end

  context "when the names are correct" do
    its(:team_names) do
      is_expected.to include('Dogs')
      is_expected.to include('Cats')
    end
end
```

So in my test I am testing `team_names` method. In `before..end` I mock a call to the database and expect it to return `team_1`. If I do that, the first test case will fail, but the second one will pass. That makes sense. But I want to mock two calls to db and return `teams` so I can test that my method return the names from both teams. I tried this in test file:

```rb
#....
before do
    allow(MyMongoGem::DB['teams']).to receive_message_chain(:find, :first)
      .with(any_args)
      .and_return team_1
   allow(MyMongoGem::DB['teams']).to receive_message_chain(:find, :first)
      .with(any_args)
      .and_return team_2

    subject.deliver!
  end
#.....
end
```

But the second call overwrites the first one. And now the first test case will pass but the second fail. The output would be `['Dogs', 'Dogs']` instead of `[Cats', 'Dogs']`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can supply your own block when stubbing a method, like so:

```
allow(MyMongoGem::DB['teams']).to receive_message_chain(:find, :first) do |_|
    team_names.pop
end
```

where `team_names` would be a list of the team names you need, `team_names = %w[Cats Dogs]`, in whatever order you want (note that `team_names.pop` returns the last element in the list, while `team_names.shift` returns the first)